# Difficulty with push method while creating a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

I want to create a function that logs out "I have 1 bottle. I have 2 bottles. I have 3 bottles" and so on, to the console.
But I keep getting the output below:

```
I have 1 bottle
I have 1 bottle,bottle
I have 1 bottle,bottle,bottle
```

```js
let word = []

function test() {
  let x = 1
  if (x <= 1) {
    word.push("bottle")
    console.log("I have " + x + " " + word)
  } else if (x > 1) {
    word.push("bottles")
    console.log("I have " + x + " " + word)
  }

  x++
}

test()
test()
test()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, **console output**, markup, data, data structures, and other textual information **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: "the statement below." - what does that mean? Do you have any specific question about that code snippet?

Comment: When you push an element to an array, you add to the array's contents. So the previous element(s) are still there, and you're adding another one. When you output the array using `+ word`, the default array-to-string method is called, which outputs the array's elements with commas between them. If all you want to do is generate the console output you've mentioned, you don't need an array at all. (And you certainly don't want one you create outside the function.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks a lot. You made it clearer to me now. I edited the code and it worked.

Comment: Use a [generator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77880787/1762224) for this.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let word = []
let x = 1

function test() {
  if (x === 1) {
    word.push("bottle")
    console.log("I have " + x + " " + word.join(", "))
  } else if (x > 1) {
    word.push("bottles")
    console.log("I have " + x + " " + word.join(", "))
  }

  x++
}

test()
test()
test()
```

like that ?

Comment: Yes, the problem was with the word array.  I used a normal bracket and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect use case for a [generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator).

```js
const pluralRules = new Intl.PluralRules('en-US');

function pluralize(count, singular, plural) {
  const rule = pluralRules.select(count);
  switch (rule) {
    case 'one'   : return `${count} ${singular}`;
    case 'other' : return `${count} ${plural ?? singular + 's'}`;
    default      : throw new Error(`Unknown: ${rule}`);
  }
}

function* bottleGenerator() {
  let count = 0;
  while (true) {
    yield `I have ${pluralize(++count, 'bottle')}`;
  }
};

const gen = bottleGenerator();

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  console.log(gen.next().value);
}
```

Here is a more quick-and-dirty-approach:

```js
const bottleGenerator = function* () {
  yield `I have 1 bottle`;
  let count = 1;
  while (true) yield `I have ${++count} bottles`;
};

const gen = bottleGenerator();
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  console.log(gen.next().value);
}
```

And here is an alternative that uses an enhanced for-loop:

```js
const bottleGenerator = function* () {
  yield `I have 1 bottle`;
  let count = 1;
  while (true) yield `I have ${++count} bottles`;
};

let limit = 3;
for (let value of bottleGenerator()) {
  console.log(value);
  if (--limit <= 0) break; // Exit
}
```